# How to put containers network to the kubernetes YAML file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, networking, kubernetes

For exmaple, I created network at docker

```
docker network create hello-rails
```

Then, I have mySQL, which is connected to this network

```
docker run -p 3306 -d --network=hello-rails --network-alias=db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name hello-rails-db mysql
```

And also, I have rails server, which also rely on this network

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --network=hello-rails -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_HOST=db --name hello-rails benjamincaldwell/hello-docker-rails:latest
```

I want to write deployment on kubernetes for these two containers with YAML file. But I don't know, how to put network inside `containers` in the file. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes you would solve this by creating two services.

The MySQL service will look something like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - port: 3306
```

In your rails server, you can access the MySQL service by either using the `mysql` DNS name or using the `MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST` and `MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT` environment variables. There is no need to link the containers or specifying a network, as would be done in Docker.

Your Rails service will look like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rails
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: rails
  ports:
  - port: 3000
```

Notice the `type: LoadBalancer`, which specifies that this service will be published to the outside world. Depending on where you run Kubernetes, a public IP address will be automatically assigned to this service.

For more information, have a look at the [Services documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

Comment: Thank you! And last question, is it possible to combine them into one app with kubectl create -f ?

Comment: Yes, I would even recommend it. You can combine all kinds of resources in one Yaml file, separated by a line with `---`, [like this](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml). But *create* (or *apply*, which I recommend), can also be called with a directory and they will consider all files in that directory.

Comment: So, I need to combine this two services into one deploymen/t

Comment: When you run `kubectl apply`, Kubernetes will create a deployment for each service, no matter if these services have been defined in one or two files. Both configurations are possible, but having resources that belong together in one file [is recommended](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/).